# ImageResizer: How to install s3reader2 plugin

Tags: imageresizer

I have installed Imageresizer on IIS. Locally it works fine.
I am really confused about s3Reader2 plugin. What and where i should to copy?
I've tried to copy s3reader2 folder from plugins folder to

- /bin folder - /bin/plugins folder - /plugins folder

Then i tried to copy ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2 dll form /dlls/release and it is not works too.
Here is my diagnostic sheet:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      localhost   4/10/2016 2:38:12 PM

3 Issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


Plugins(ConfigurationError):    Failed to load plugin by name "(S3Reader2, )"
            Verify that "ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2"  is located in /bin. 
            Attempted using "(S3Reader2, )", "ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2.S3Reader2, ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2".

(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use

Assembly use report: 

You do not seem to be using any plugins from (commerical/AGPL) editions.



Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin

Configuration:

<resizer>
<plugins>
<add name="S3Reader2" prefix="~/s3" region="eu-central-1" buckets="xxxxxxxxx" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/8.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.34209
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: AMD64
Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlRoutingModule-4.0)
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under keyScriptModule-4.0)
System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyOutputCache)
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keySession)
System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyWindowsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFormsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyDefaultAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyRoleManager)
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyFileAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyAnonymousIdentification)
System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyProfile)
System.Web.UrlMappingsModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under keyUrlMappingsModule)
ImageResizer.InterceptModule, ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null          (under keyImageResizingModule)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34274 Info: 4.0.30319.34274
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34239 Info: 4.0.30319.34239
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34274 Info: 4.0.30319.34274
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 12.0.20806.33440 Info: 12.0.20806.33440
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34274 Info: 4.0.30319.34274
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34262 Info: 4.0.30319.34262
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34209 Info: 4.0.30319.34209
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34230 Info: 4.0.30319.34230
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.34262 Info: 4.0.30319.34262
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.33440 Info: 4.0.30319.33440
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0
ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0

The following plugin assemblies are loaded but do not seem to be in use. You should remove them (and especially their dependencies (unless used elsewhere)) from the /bin folder to improve application load times:

ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.5.942       Info: 4.0.5  Commit: 3d5572f812a7c9252402583ffbb006d08baa90f0

Reference list of plugin dependencies - so you know what additional dlls to remove when removing a plugin. (may not be up-to-date, see plugin docs):

The FreeImage plugin has the following dependencies: FreeImage.dll and FreeImageNET.dll
The Logging plugin depends on: NLog.dll
The AdvancedFilters, RedEye, and WhitespaceTrimmer plugins depend on: AForge.dll, AForge.Math.dll, and AForge.Imaging.dll
The PsdReader and PsdComposer plugins depend on: PsdFile.dll
The S3Reader plugin depends on: AWSSDK.dll
The BatchZipper plugin depends on: Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll
The PdfRenderer plugin depends on gsdll32.dll or gdsll32.dll
The RedEye plugin depends on several dozen files... see the plugin docs.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you use NuGet: `Install-Package ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader2`

S3Reader2 depends on AWSSDK, so you'll need those dlls as well if it is to load properly. They change over time, so NuGet is your friend here.

Comment: Nathanael thanks. But I am not a developer and have no clue how to manage with build this app. But -yes I ask for developer from my team and he build the application. Only the question- why you did not make install OOTB or just not describre how to install from the box?